# How to queryset all user that are in a foreign table?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model called book and in that model there is a foreignkey field (called author) to the user model.

I need in one of my views to returm a list of all the authors(not all users, just users that appear in the book model(just the authors).

I don't know why, but i'm having a hard time getting that.

Can any one please help me with this?

10x,

Erez

Comment: It's easier to answer questions like this when you show your models, or a simplified version of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, usualy i put some code, but I thought that in this case it is not relevant....If needed i will do that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).distinct()
```

I'm assuming there is only one foreign key from the `Book` model to the `User` model.

- [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) filters for all users which are in the which are linked to the `Book` model.
- [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) ensures that each author only appears once in the results.

Comment: First, 10x, i'm trying what you wrote but i am having a new problem... Can i use a related_name instead of the the User model? I have a related name in the Book model for the author field that is called book_author, beacouse the reverse loop for User take to another model..... so, Can i user the selated_name instead?

Comment: If the foreign key to User has a related name, replace book__isnull with related name__isnull.

Comment: I can't reply again until next week, so if my comment above doesn't help, hopefully somebody else can.

Comment: 10x, working great, no i know how to do outer join in (kind of...) in django :-) This is soooooo cool :-)